# ConnectionError: Connection is closed. ECONNCLOSED when using SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I've been trying to connect to my SQL Server Express database for forever now, but I keep getting caught with this error message. I tried to go back to the code being as simple as possible.

```
const express = require('express')
const sql = require('mssql')

const config = {
  user:'user',
  password:'pass',
  server:'servername',
  database:'database',
  options:{
    encrypt:true,
    enableArithAbort:true
  }
}

let dbConn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
dbConn.connect().then(()=>{
  let request = new sql.Request(config)
  request.query("SELECT * FROM id").then((resp)=>{
    console.log(resp)
  }).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
  })
})
```

> ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
> at Request._query (D:\RandomCodeProjects\NodeJS\discordBotServer\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:469:37)
> at Request._query (D:\RandomCodeProjects\NodeJS\discordBotServer\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:353:11)
> at D:\RandomCodeProjects\NodeJS\discordBotServer\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:433:12
> at new Promise ()
> at Request.query (D:\RandomCodeProjects\NodeJS\discordBotServer\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:432:12)
> at D:\RandomCodeProjects\NodeJS\discordBotServer\index.js:18:11 {
> code: 'ECONNCLOSED'
> }